# Bash formatting for nice ascii logs

Tags: linux, bash, logging, ascii

I've written a function to do some logging on different aspects of the files, folder, etc and I 'm going to have this automatically email members of my staff. All this is fine but I wouldn't mind some pointers and help to make the formation nicer - this will get sent out via mailutils as part of the script.

Just looking for some nice spacing tips,etc

```
function report(){
lsb_release -a
echo "OS:               $(uname -s)"
echo "ARCH:             $(uname -m)"
echo "VER:              $(uname -r)"

echo "Apache running "
ps aux|grep -i apache2

echo "Showing if SSL is open"
apache2ctl -M | grep ssl

echo "Space on local disk"
df -h

echo "Showing permissions for the web folders"
echo $'*** /var/www// ***'
ls -l /var/www | awk '{print $1 "  " $3 "  " $4 "  " $9}'
ls -l /var/www/user1 | awk '{print $1 "  " $3 "  " $4 "  " $9}'
ls -l /var/www/user2 | awk '{print $1 "  " $3 "  " $4 "  " $9}'

echo "Showing network status"
ifconfig eth0
echo " DNS "
tail /etc/resolv.conf

echo "Current workspaces set up on the local server "
grep user2 /var/www/temp/text.txt | grep -E -o '[0-9]+[0-9]'

}
```

Comment: Can you give some sample output, with commentary about what you think is less than ideal, and/or your specific vision of what the output should be?

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the "column" command instead of or after using awk or cut.

```
ls -l | awk '{print $1" "$3" "$4" "$9}' | tail -n +2 | column -t
```

Check out the difference between "mount" and "mount | column -t" or "df -PH and df -PH | column -t"

If you want to concatenate columns of info with the same number or relational fields you can use process redirection and "paste."

```
paste -d ' ' <(cat /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/device/fc_host:host*/port_name) \
             <(cat /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/device/fc_host:host*/speed) \
             <(cat /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/device/fc_host:host*/port_state)
0x218000e05a0001aa 4 Gbit Online
0x218000e05a2001aa 4 Gbit Online
```